# How can I apply a condition on specific field of a specific index in a multi (global) index search in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I want to do a global search on those two indexes : themes, users.

Those two indexes have those fields :

users : [first_name]
themes: [title, description, is_public]

I'm using right now this query :

```
{"query":
    {"bool":
        {"should":[
            {"wildcard": {"first_name": "*usicTerm"}},
            {"wildcard": {"title": "*usicTerm"}},
        ]},
        "index": ["users", "themes"]
    },
    "from":0,"size":10,"sort":[]
}
```

Now here's the thing, I want to filter all themes results by a specific theme field called "is_public", so I tried :

```
{"query":
    {"bool":
        {"should":[
            {"wildcard": {"first_name": "*usicTerm"}},
            {"wildcard": {"title": "*usicTerm"}}
        ]},
        {"must": [
             {"term": {"is_public": true}}
        ]}
        "index": ["users", "themes"]
    },
    "from":0,"size":10,"sort":[]
}
```

But this doesn't work as it's also filtering out all users index results not having a field "is_public" to true because this index doesn't even have this field !

So any one can tell me how I can apply this "must" clause only on my "theme" index ?

Thank you :)

David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If is_public is always present (so it is false or true, never missing from document), you could try following approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "is_public"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "is_public": "true"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There were changes to filters in ES 2.0 so maybe it will look a little bit different, depending on what ES version you're using.